# How to avoid Xcode from doing an static analysis of all the files?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a project with sqlite3 amalgamated in it in a separate static lib project but xcode is burning my cpu since it's a 4MB source file. I can't find a way to say that exclude that file during the static analysis.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to avoid Xcode, eg. by using just make, gcc, emacs in terminals?

Comment: good idea! will switch to emacs now! have to ship a product tomorrow still debugging, will master gcc & emacs in a few minutes right?

Answer (score 1):

As kenji mentioned in their comment, create a static library from your custom sqlite source code and include that in your builds. It won't be recompiled each time and will not be analyzed. You can do this as an Xcode sub-project.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your analyse logs in xcode, you'll see that it's don't analyse resources (pngs, jpgs, xib, etc) files.

If you look at the usage of the clang analyzer (which is integrated into xcode), it says :

"The scan-build command can be used to analyze an entire project by essentially interposing on a project's build process. This means that to run the analyzer using scan-build, you will use scan-build to analyze the source files compiled by gcc during a project build. This means that any files that are not compiled will also not be analyzed."

Extracted from : http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html

Comment: the 4MB file is a source file, I didn't mention that.

Comment: Is your static lib compiled each time with your project ? If it's the case, maybe you can just add the lib.a and corresponding headers in your project. The analyser won't scan already compiled code.